# Using Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, partial

I am using MVC 3 razor for a web application. My requirement is to create a wizard like feel, for this i am using independent views for each step. I want to use a partial view having Previous, Cancel and Next buttons so that on each step i could use this partial view. Please suggest how can i go with approach and how to decide what action will be called on Previous and Next button.

Many thanks

Regards
Viv

Answer (score 0):

I would probably make something like "Step" action in a Controller. This Action would accept id parameter (int). Then I would probably use something like: (pseudocode)

```
// Checking what Id you got from url
// Setting int id = ...
//

// And then
switch(id)
{
  case 1: return View(view1);
  case 2: return View(view2);
  case 3: return View(view3);
}
```

Url will then look like:

```
/Controller/Step/Id
```

And you can point to specific step just by choosing that last part of url. Like:

```
<a href="http://localhost/myApp/Controller/Step/3">Step 3</a>
```

**Edit after comments:**
You can use ViewBag property in controller if you need dynamic behaviour.

```
switch(id)
{
  case 1:
  {
    ViewBag.PrevStep = 0;
    ViewBag.NextStep = 2;
    return View(view1);
  }
  case 2:
  {
    ViewBag.PrevStep = 1;
    ViewBag.NextStep = 3;
    return View(view2);
  }
  // etc...
}
```

Then in your view, you will make links like:

```
<a href="http://localhost/myApp/Controller/Step/@ViewBag.PrevStep">Previous step</a>
<a href="http://localhost/myApp/Controller/Step/@ViewBag.NextStep">Next step</a>
```

You can of course @Html.ActionLink, but I can't remember correct syntax for it right now :)

But still.. if you have specific View for each step then you can just hardcode these links in views.

Comment: Hi dampe thanks for replying, but how would i pass the id from previous next buttons of partial view to controller??  or may be something like say if i am on step 2 from here i could set some property of partial view like on next click step is 3 and on previous click step should be 1.something like this.any thoughts?

Comment: You said that every step has its specific view, right? Then you can just hardcode the links in views. Or if you need it more dynamic, then you can use ViewBag property. (I am going to edit my answer).

Comment: What I am doing is on each view action i set the ViewBag.Next and ViewBag.Prev and call an action with these values and call the relevant view.Well it works but will try to find some other method also. Thanks for your all help.